# Popover displacing from position when zooming OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, popup, markers

I have some markers in position with OpenLayers 3, and now I am trying to get the Popover onto them.

The problem is that when zooming in/out, Popovers don't remain with the marker. I want to make it such that when I am zooming in/out the Popover remains with the marker.

To get coordinates I am using a click function and I fetch the pixel coordinates on the click.

```
  private markerBubble(ev:any){
   var _this=this;
    const marker_bubble: HTMLElement = document.createElement("div");
    marker_bubble.setAttribute("class", "marker-bubble");
    this.info_bubble.appendChild(marker_bubble);
    marker_bubble.innerHTML = "Test1 123";
    var pixel = _this.map.getEventPixel(ev.originalEvent);
    console.log(pixel,"markerbubble");

    $(marker_bubble).css({
        top: pixel[1] - UtilityConst.ENTITY_MOVEMENT_CONST.PlayControl_TOP_DELTA,
        left: pixel[0] + UtilityConst.ENTITY_MOVEMENT_CONST.PlayControl_LEFT_DELTA,
        position: "absolute",
        background:"white"
    });
    $('.marker-bubble').draggable();


}
```

Here is the click function I am using:

```
 private handleClickOnMap(ev: any) {
    var _this=this;
    if (this.canSelectMarkers()) {
        const evt: MouseEvent = ev.originalEvent;
        // process only if markers found on click
        const features = this.getFeatureListByEvent(ev); // GIS specific event object needs to be passed here
         this.checkAndExpandOverlappedMarkers(features, ev);
        if (features.length > 0) {
                //popup to be placed.

                var pixel = _this.map.getEventPixel(ev.originalEvent);
                this.markerBubble(ev);

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: i faced the same problem , did you find solution to this?